# gdb7.7 does not load shared libraries

Tags: gdb

Perhaps, i misunderstand something, but i can't make Gdb to read debug libraries.
what i do from command line is:

```
gdb
file problem_exec
b main
r
```

GDB stops at:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/.../problem_exec

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=<error reading variable: Could not find the frame base for "main(int, char**)".>, argv=<error reading variable: Could not find the frame base for "main(int, char**)".>)
```

No shared libraries:

```
(gdb) info shared
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
```

The last command gives: "*No shared libraries loaded at this time.*"

My *.gdbinit* looks like:

```
# file .gdbinit
set stop-on-solib-events 1
# stop gdb from stepping over functions and output diagnostics
set step-mode on
set breakpoint pending on
set env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH path1:path2:path3
#automatically load shared libraries (on/off):
set auto-solib-add on
```

I am sure that an executable is linked against debug version of the shared libraries (in total there are some 30 libraries, but the one I am interested in is definitely compiled in a debug mode). I checked it with *otool -L problem_exec*

If I run program, it goes until a run-time error in the library I want to debug, but i can not step in.
Am I missing something?

p.s. I run self-compiled version of Gdb on os-x.

UPDATE: it could be related to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581645/gdb-7-7-does-not-step-in-on-os-x-mavericks-with-gcc4-7-3-macports).

Answer (score 2):

> `set stop-on-solib-events 1`

With that setting, GDB should stop *before* any shared libraries are loaded.

When you do this:

```
file problem_exec
b main
r
    ... where is GDB stopped?
info shared
```

If GDB is stopped at `main`, then shared libraries should be loaded. But if it is stopped in the dynamic loader (as I expect it is), then they should *not* be loaded *yet*.

Comment: i updated the questions, seems it stops at the main, but no shared libs are loaded anyway