# gdb 7.7 does not step-in on OS-X Mavericks with gcc4.7.3 (Macports)

Tags: c++, macos, gdb, osx-mavericks

Here is a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace Example
{

  template <int dim>
  class Problem
  {
  public:

    void run() {
        std::cout<<"here.."<<std::endl;
    }   
  };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Example::Problem<2> problem;
  problem.run();
  return 0;
}
```

compiled with Macport's gcc 4.7.3:

```
g++-mp-4.7 -g -O0 prog.cc -o prog
```

If I try to debug in gdb 7.7 (**self-compiled**, not Macport's one!):

```
$gdb
file prog
b main
r
s
```

**I can't step-in the function**:

```
34    problem.run();
(gdb) s
here..
36    return 0;
(gdb)
```

Am i doing something wrong? Or does it look like a bug of gdb when used on os-x mavericks?

**UPDATE**:

I don't see any warning/errors when using gdb:

```
$ gdb ./prog
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./prog...Reading symbols from /Users/bla-bla-bla/prog.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/prog...done.
done.
(gdb)
```

also '-gdwarf-2 -gstrict-dwarf' do not change the behaviour....

**UDAPTE2**:

I see the same missing call-stack behaviour as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909547/missing-call-stack-frame-with-assert-for-gdb-7-6-on-mac). Although I was not able to check if compiling with `-m32` helps in my case, since I have everything for 64bit and thus get `undefined symbols` problems.

Another stepping problem while debugging is reported [here](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2014-02/msg00023.html) and here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16756911/gcc-4-7-3-and-gdb-7-6-on-mac-strange-stepping-problems).

Comment: You do know you have *undefined behavior* in your code? You create a vector containing five elements, but then you assign to the eleventh element. That means all bets are off.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sure, it's just a stupid example, the point is not the code, but inability to step-in.

Comment: The point is, with undefined behavior you can't say what will happen. Like I said, all bets are off. Yes, it will probably not do anything in this specific case, but as long as you have undefined behavior you can't say anything about the behavior about the program or how the debugger will work or not work when running it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so you are saying that it is normal that I can't step-in the function and actually go line-by-line and debug?..

Comment: @JoachimPileborg p.s. updated the question to avoid this discussion....

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **-gdwarf-2** option along with -g to debug using gdb for newer version of gcc.

> g++-mp-4.7 -g -gdwarf-2 -O0 prog.cc -o prog

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but this did not change the behaviour... :(

Comment: @Denis: It looks like there is some problem/bug on the gdb macport and you can find more information on the link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11705195/2724703

Comment: thanks for the link, i don't experience any GDB warning/errors, but it could easily be related...